# RSpec Scenario Outlines: Multiple Test Cases

Tags: unit-testing, templates, rspec, cucumber

What's the best way to test a bunch of different test cases with RSpec?

For example, given [string-additions.rb](https://gist.github.com/899520):

```
require 'rspec'

class String
  if method_defined? :reverse_words
    raise "String#reverse_words is already defined"
  end
  def reverse_words
    split(' ').reverse!.join(' ')
  end
end

describe String do
  describe "#reverse_words" do
    specify { "hello".reverse_words.should eq("hello") }
    specify { "hello world".reverse_words.should eq("world hello") }
    specify { "bob & pop run".reverse_words.should eq("run pop & bob") }
  end
end
```

when I run `rspec string-additions.rb --color --format doc`, I get:

```
String
  #reverse_words
    should == hello
    should == world hello
    should == run pop & bob
```

However, I'd like to get sensible output, like this:

```
String
  #reverse_words
    "hello" => "hello"
    "hello world" => "world hello"
    "bob & pop run" => "run pop & bob"
```

And, I'd like to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up my specs a bit. Does RSpec provide a template for DRYing up this sort of multiple-case testing? Something similar to [Cucumber scenario outlines](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/scenario-outlines)?

Note: This question is similar to [Is there an equivalent in RSpec to Cucumber's “Scenarios” or am I using RSpec the wrong way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679875/is-there-an-equivalent-in-rspec-to-cucumbers-scenarios-or-am-i-using-rspec-the) but provides an example that should be tested with RSpec rather than Cucumber.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading [Elisabeth Hendrickson's Adventures with Auto-Generated Tests and RSpec](http://testobsessed.com/2009/09/04/adventures-with-auto-generated-tests-and-rspec/), I came up with this solution:

```
describe String do
  describe "#reverse_words" do
    strings = {
      "hello"         => "hello",
      "hello world"   => "world hello",
      "bob & pop run" => "run pop & bob"
    }

    strings.each do |k, v|
      specify "\"#{k}\" => \"#{v}\"" do
        k.reverse_words.should eq(v)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This gives the output I want, but it'd be nicer if RSpec had a template to make things even DRYer.