# Cucumber's multi-example tables for Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, cucumber

Is there something similar to Cucumber's multi-example tables (using pickle) for Rspec acceptance specs (capybara)?

Would be very convenient for testing multiple scenarios and outcomes without having to recreate each spec with only minor parameter differences.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679875/is-there-an-equivalent-in-rspec-to-cucumbers-scenarios-or-am-i-using-rspec-the

Comment: I'll double your interest in that though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a spec in an `each` block, or put an `each` block in a spec.

But I'd recommend using Cucumber. RSpec acceptance tests are quite painful by comparison.